# MySQL JSON array - order by last key

Tags: json

I have the column 'updated_at' in which I save all the changes as following:

```
{date:{type_of_change: original => new},date:{...},and so on}
```

I now want to sort by the last element/date of the json array, as the last element is the latest update. I also want to know how I can select the rows where the last element has the type_of_change equal to "some value".

Comment: what version of mysql are you using?  There are a lot of useful things in MYSQL 8.0 is the reason I'm asking

Comment: The latest version. Can't tell any specific version number but I updated it a few weeks ago to the newest one.